# Python password with three attempts

Tags: python

I just create a password verification process. The program asks users for a password; they have three attempts. If they did not correct, then ask them to try again. it just does not run correctly.

if I type "Tom" as a password, it not runs into access granted. moreover, after I tried two attempts, the "try three" is not showing up.

```
password = 'Tom'
count = 0
while count <= 3:
     Question = input('Please enter the password: try1')
     if Question == password:
       print('Access granted Pass 1')
       break
     while count <= 2:
         Question = input('That is incorrect, please try again: trytwo')
         count += 2
     while count <= 1 :
        Question = input('That is incorrect, please try again: trythree')

     else:
        print('Access denied')
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use while loops incorrectly in this case

```py
password = 'Tom'
count = 1
while count <= 3:
     Question = input('Please enter the password: try{}'.format(count))
     if Question == password:
       print('Access granted Pass {}'.format(count))
       break
     else:
       print("That is incorrect, please try again")
       count+=1
if count == 4:
        print('Access denied')
        count += 1
```